# Using jQuery to retrieve customizer value

Tags: jquery, theme-options, theme-customizer

I am trying to use jQuery to retrieve a theme options (customizer) value:

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_fixed', array(
        'default'   => true,
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_fixed', array(
        'label'     => __( 'Enable fixed navigation?', 'theme' ),
        'section'   => 'header_section',
        'settings'  => 'header_fixed',
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'priority' => 40,
    ) ) );
```

If the above value is true, then the header element will be fixed position. If not, it will be relative position (a class will be added, or not, with jQuery). I'm not terribly competent with jQuery, so the following is based on what comes in customizer.js, from _s:

```
    wp.customize( 'header_fixed', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        if ( 'true' == to ) {
            $( '#header-inner' ).addClass( 'fixed' );
        }
    } );
} );
```

I've been placing this in customizer.js as doing so elsewhere results in an error: 'wp' is not defined.

Edit* I'm enqueuing the script as follows:

```
function theme_customize_preview_js() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/js/customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ) );
} 
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'theme_customize_preview_js' );
```

Edit** This seems not to be quite possible at this time, so I ended up doing it with PHP:

```
<?php if ( '' != get_theme_mod( 'header_fixed') ) echo 'fixed'; ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us how you register the script and _when_ (as in action/filter) you are calling it. If it's not defined, it's too early.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited the above accordingly (hopefully I've understood you).

Answer (score 0):

Use that JQuery code from your question in customizer preview for real time update. Your transport should be set to 'postMessage'. In your website you can add body class in function.php:

```
function theme_prefix_body_class( $classes ) {

    if ( get_theme_mod('header_fixed', 0 ) == true  ) {

        $classes[] = 'fixed-header';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'theme_prefix_body_class' );
```

Comment: I'm not actually looking to add a body class (through PHP, no less), but I might just end up doing something like this. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: 1. You can't use JQuery code from above outside of the customizer screen. 2. If you want access options in JQuery you should print them from php first. 3.  You can't use 'jQuery to retrieve a theme options (customizer) value' outside of the customizer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) It looks like it may be a future possibility, however (if the following enhancement is any indication): https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/27/toward-a-complete-javascript-api-for-the-customizer/